# How to pass pipeline model to a class without instantiating it

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to create a class that takes a scikit-learn pipeline and loop over it (as in the code example below).

In the example below I can however only pass the instance of my pipeline to the class and not create a new one in order to start with a fresh model.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


class my_class:
    def __init__(self,model):
        self.model = model
    def evaluate(self, X, y):
        results = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.model.fit(X,y) #I always use the same instance here.
            y_pred = self.model.predict(X)
            results.append(accuracy_score(y_pred=y_pred, y_true=y))
        return results 

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('classifier', AdaBoostClassifier())
])

test = my_class(pipeline)
scores = test.evaluate(X,y)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the class and why do you want to loop over the pipeline? Change model-Parameters? The `i`-iterator is unused in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be initializing different models but the result will always be the same because you are training and testing on the same data `X` every time without any change in the hyperparameters and `random_state` as `None`. That is why the `results` list will always contain same value.